# change x-axis position in BarChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

How to change x-axis position from the bottom to 0th Y-axis value in BarChart ?

I have bar chart with some negative values right now, x axis is starting with lowest negative value of y axis. I want to change that position to Zero value of y-axis.

currently I have this

- 10
- 5
- 0
- -5
- 10 ----Domain axis Here

I want

- 10
- 5
- 0---- Domain axis here
- -5
- -10

  Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, 
try something like this:

```
NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) xyplot.getRangeAxis();
yAxis.setLowerBound(0);
```

Comment: yAxis.setLowerBound(0); will start y-axis values from the zero & it is avoiding negative values. I want to show negative values plus to show domain axis values to 0th level like i have mentioned in the above example. Thanks!